# reputation stat mismatch username hover & user profile reputation tab

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, user-interface

I did notice something odd today. There was a -15 from my reputation score, but the stat. on username hover says it is just -5.

Digging reputation tab on my profile page reveal there is actually -15 (unaccept) on single post. No other upvotes or anything logged.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), the hover at the top is "recent" reputation changes, the exact range depends on your activity level (we go back until we have a decent amount to populate)...for you that's "this month".

If you look at December 3rd you have +10 on that from an upvote...so -15 + 10 = -5 is the correct *net* reputation change from that post "recently".

Comment: thank you for the clarification.